# Adding CityGML as vector layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, import, citygml

Is there a possibility to add CityGML data to my QGIS Project?
If I want to add it as a vector layer. QGIS always freezes and doesn't work anymore.

After googling I found the Plugin CityJSON but I don't get how it works. Can anybody help?

Comment: The sample CityGML of Delft from here https://3d.bk.tudelft.nl/opendata/3dfier/ works absolutely fine in my QGIS v3.20. Does it work for you? Is the problem with your data? How big and complex is it?

Comment: The file is 650 MB big... I don´t know how complex it is. I can not open it.

Comment: Does the Delft example I linked to work for you? That is 242Mb in size (so about 1/3 of yours) but its possible 650Mb is too big for the RAM in your machine or the data are too complex. Impossible to know without the data and your machine specification. But in principle, CityGML loads into QGIS like any other layer, subject to those constraints. Maybe you just need more RAM? Or to subset the data if you only need to work on part of it.